# How do I change an image text in a menu class within wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am changing a service line within my website and I am trying to be consistent throughout the website of the name change.

http://carnahangroup.com/our-expertise/medical-equipment-appraisals/

i.e. Medical Equipment Appraisals from Tangible Asset Valuations

Image from website visitor view:

[image: Image from website visitor view]

code from the WordPress:

[image: code from the wordpress]

Comment: @weisen that would be extremely helpful. Do you know of any avenues for chatting?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the menu on your wordpress admin and look for "Services Icons" menu to see if you can change it there. :)

Comment: Weisen thanks for you response. I do have a service icons menu hwoever I do not understand how to add an image with the name "medical equipment appraisals"

Comment: @MattMaerz, i'm not sure how to possibly show it to you here but maybe we can do a chat somewhere so I can explain it to you further and help you out.

Comment: Let me know whenever you get the chance!

Comment: I'm online @MattMaerz, how can we get in touch then? :)

Comment: Not sure...very basic wordpress skills and stack overflow platform skills...I can share my screen over a gotomeeting platform?

Comment: Maybe we can bring this over via email instead rather than chatting here so I can assist. Let me know your email address so I can communicate with you outside SO to help. :)

Comment: sure thing...my email is matthewjmaerz@yahoo.com